# How do I split a comma-separated string in a SQL Server table using MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server table `Product` with a column `ProductAvailableSizes` that records the sizes which are currently available for a product.

So I might have `ProductAvailableSizes = 38, 39, 40, 41`. I want this string to be split in my mvc view and each of these string should be placed in a div without **comma**.

Anyone who used an online web shop may know what I mean. I haven't tried anything so far as I am very new to the programming. Help please.

Comment: Start using string.split, then come back here if you get stuck

Comment: Use the `string.Split()` method to convert to an an array of values (and then use a loop in the view).

Comment: Refactor your database and normalize that column into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Split` method, Something like this inside your view:

```
@{
    var ProductAvailableSizes = Model.ProductAvailableSizes.Split(',');
}
foreach(var item in ProductAvailableSizes) 
{
   <div>@item</div>
}
```